# Numpy mask to count number of elements satisfying a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

How to use Numpy to vectorize this for loop?

```
count=0
arr1 = np.random.rand(184,184)
for i in range(arr1.size[0]):
    for j in range(arr1.size[1]):
        if arr1[i,j] > 0.6:
            count += 1
print count
```

I tried:

```
count=0
arr1 = np.random.rand(184,184)
mask = (arr1>0.6)
indices = np.where(mask)
print indices , len(indices)
```

I expected len(indices) to give count, but it didn't. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Get a boolean mask and just count the "True"s:

```
(arr1 > 0.6).sum()
```

Comment: This is such a compact and simple solution showing the true power of numpy. It's great how both stages of of where and count are joined together. Thanks for a great answer!

Answer (score 27):

`np.count_nonzero` should be a bit faster than the sum:

```
np.count_nonzero(arr1 > 0.6)
```

In fact, it is three times as fast

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=10000)
>>> 
>>> arr1 = np.random.rand(184,184)
>>> 
>>> repeat('np.count_nonzero(arr1 > 0.6)', **kwds)
[0.15281831508036703, 0.1485864429268986, 0.1477385900216177]
>>> repeat('(arr1 > 0.6).sum()', **kwds)
[0.5286932559683919, 0.5260644309455529, 0.5260107989888638]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **size** attribute of **Numpy** array:

```
arr1 = np.random.rand(184,184)

arr1[ arr1 > 0.6 ].size
```

Comment: Surprisingly, accessing this property is over an order of magnitude slower than `np.count_nonzero` but I couldn't find any explanation as to why.