# Python - Number of occurrence of an event

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array as follow:

```
a = [1 2 5 3 8 7 2 9 8]
```

and a constant number `b=4`

How can I count the occurrence `c` of `a` being inferior to `b`?

So in this example `c=4`

Comment: If it's a numpy array then `(a<b).sum()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy mask to count number of elements satisfying a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49762199/numpy-mask-to-count-number-of-elements-satisfying-a-condition) or [How to count values in a certain range in a Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560207/how-to-count-values-in-a-certain-range-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: It is a numy array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using numpy:

```
np.sum(a < 4)
```

Or a `sum` on generator:

```
sum(num < 4 for num in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "less than" by "inferior", you can use a [list comprehension](https://medium.com/better-programming/list-comprehension-in-python-8895a785550b)

```
c = len([x for x in a if x < b])
```

If you're worried about space constraints, you can use a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) like Alexander's answer.

```
sum(1 if num < b else 0 for num in a)
```

Comment: If you're worried about space contraints, use a generator like Alexander's solution

Comment: Thanks! I will update

Comment: Now you just copied the other answer, without attribution...

Comment: You're right. I should cite him.