# Count the number of times elements in a numpy array consecutively satisfy a condition

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `numpy` array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8])
```

and a constant number `b=6`

I am searching for a number `c` which is defined by the number of times the elements in `a` are less than `b` 2 or more times consecutively.

So in this example it `c=3`

I have no working code, that's why I am asking that here. Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874401/python-number-of-occurrence-of-an-event) I can use `np.sum(a<b)` to get the number of times that `a<b`.

```
print(np.sum(a<b))
#12
```

Now I want to count the number of times where `a` is two or more times consecutively less than `b`.

Here is an illustration of the 3 groups in for this sample `a`:

```
1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8  # numbers in a
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0  # (a<b)
^^^^^^^-----^^^^-----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^---  # (a<b) 2+ times consecutively
   1         2                                    3
```

Comment: it is maybe not clear but the condition is defined by the number of times that `a` is inferior to `b` at least 2 times consecutively so `c=3`

Comment: For future reference: you'll get a more positive response in general if  you share your attempt at solving the problem yourself, even if that attempt is inefficient or doesn't work. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy` masking and `itertools.groupby`.

```
from itertools import groupby

b = 6
sum(len(list(g))>=2 for i, g in groupby(a < b) if i)
#3
```