# Get groups of consecutive elements of a NumPy array based on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, grouping

I have a NumPy array as follows:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8])
```

and a constant number `b = 6`

Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874771/count-the-number-of-times-elements-in-a-numpy-array-consecutively-satisfy-a-cond?noredirect=1#comment100298414_56874771) I can count the number `c` which is defined by the number of times the elements in `a` are less than `b` 2 or more times consecutively.

```
from itertools import groupby
b = 6
sum(len(list(g))>=2 for i, g in groupby(a < b) if i)
```

so in this example `c == 3`

Now I would like to output an array each time the condition is met instead of counting the number of times the condition is met.

So with this example the right output would be:

```
array1 = [1, 4, 2]
array2 = [4, 4]
array3 = [3, 4, 4, 5]
```

since:

```
1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8  # numbers in a
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0  # (a<b)
^^^^^^^-----^^^^-----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^---  # (a<b) 2+ times consecutively
   1         2                                    3
```

So far I have tried different options:

```
np.isin((len(list(g))>=2 for i, g in groupby(a < b)if i), a)
```

and

```
np.extract((len(list(g))>=2 for i, g in groupby(a < b)if i), a)
```

But none of them achieved what I am searching for. Can someone point me to the right Python tools in order to output the different arrays satisfying my condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While measuring performance of [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889927/7851470) I noticed that while it was faster than [Austin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56888339/7851470) (for arrays of length <15000), its complexity was not linear.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353335/7851470) I came up with the following solution using [`np.split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) which is more efficent than both previously added answers here:

```
array = np.append(a, -np.inf)  # padding so we don't lose last element
mask = array >= 6  # values to be removed
split_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
for subarray in np.split(array, split_indices + 1):
    if len(subarray) > 2:
        print(subarray[:-1])
```

gives:

```
[1. 4. 2.]
[4. 4.]
[3. 4. 4. 5.]
```

Performance*:

[image]

<sup>*Measured by [perfplot](https://pypi.org/project/perfplot/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and grab the groups:

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = []
b = 6
for i, g in groupby(a, key=lambda x: x < b):
    grp = list(g)
    if i and len(grp) >= 2:
        lst.append(grp)

print(lst)

# [[1, 4, 2], [4, 4], [3, 4, 4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This task is very similar to [image labeling](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/label-and-measure-objects-in-a-binary-image.html), but, in your case, it is one-dimensional. [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html) library provides some useful functionality for image processing that we could employ here:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import (binary_dilation,
                           binary_erosion,
                           label)

a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8])
b = 6  # your threshold
min_consequent_count = 2

mask = a < b
structure = [False] + [True] * min_consequent_count  # used for erosion and dilation
eroded = binary_erosion(mask, structure)
dilated = binary_dilation(eroded, structure)
labeled_array, labels_count = label(dilated)  # labels_count == c

for label_number in range(1, labels_count + 1):  # labeling starts from 1
    subarray = a[labeled_array == label_number]
    print(subarray)
```

gives:

```
[1 4 2]
[4 4]
[3 4 4 5]
```

---

**Explanation:**

1. `mask = a < b` returns a [boolean array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) with `True` values where elements are less than the threshold `b`:

   ```
   array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False,
          False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,
           True, False])
   ```
2. As you can see the result contains some `True` elements that don't have any other `True` neighbors around them. To eliminate them we could use [binary erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)). I use [`scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html) for that purpose. Its default `structure` parameter is not suitable for our needs as it will also delete two consequent `True` values, so I construct my own:

   ```
   >>> structure = [False] + [True] * min_consequent_count
   >>> structure
   [False, True, True]
   >>> eroded = binary_erosion(mask, structure)
   >>> eroded
   array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False,
          False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
          False, False])
   ```
3. We managed to remove single `True` values but we need to get the initial configuration for other groups. In order to do so, we use [binary dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(morphology)) with the same `structure`:

   ```
   >>> dilated = binary_dilation(eroded, structure)
   >>> dilated
   array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True,  True, False, False, False,
          False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
           True, False])
   ```

   <sup>Docs for `binary_dilation`: [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_dilation.html).</sup>
4. And as a final step, we label each group with [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html):

   ```
   >>> labeled_array, labels_count = label(dilated)
   >>> labeled_array
   array([1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0])
   >>> labels_count
   3
   ```

   You can see that `labels_count` is the same as the `c` value - number of the groups in the question.
   From here you can simply get the subgroups by boolean indexing:

   ```
   >>> a[labeled_array == 1]
   array([1, 4, 2])
   >>> a[labeled_array == 3]
   array([3, 4, 4, 5])
   ```