# Get groups of consecutive elements of a NumPy array based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 NumPy array as follow:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8])
b = np.array([2, 8, 3, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 7, 2, 1, 1, 9, 9])
```

and 2 constant numbers:

```
c = 6
d = 3
```

Based on [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888201/get-groups-of-consecutive-elements-of-a-numpy-array-based-on-condition), I can extract an array each times the elements in `a` are less than `c`, 2 or more times consecutively:

```
array = np.append(a, -np.inf)  # padding so we don't lose last element
mask = array >= c  # values to be removed
split_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
for subarray in np.split(array, split_indices + 1):
    if len(subarray) > 2:
        print(subarray[:-1])
```

which output:

```
[1. 4. 2.]
[4. 4.]
[3. 4. 4. 5.]
```

Now, I would like to change my condition for a multiple condition where, 2 or more times consecutively:

1. elements in `a` are less than `c`,

AND

2. elements in `b` are less than `d`

Using the following code:

```
mask = ((a< c) & (b< d))
```

I know that my conditions (2 times or more consecutively) are just meet 1 time at indices `15`,`16` and `17`.

Now I would like to extract the value of `a` corresponding to those indices where my conditions are meet.

Based on the link answer, I tried:

```
a1= np.append(a, -np.inf)
a2=np.append(b, -np.inf)  # padding so we don't lose last element
mask = ((a1< c) & (a2< d))  # values to be removed
split_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
for subarray in np.split(a, split_indices + 1):
    if len(subarray) > 2:
        print(subarray[:-1])
```

Which surprisingly, return an array where my coonditions are not meet...

```
[4 2 6 4 4 6 2 7 6 2 8 9 3 6]
```

I also tried the `np.extract` as follow:

```
np.extract((len(list(g))>=2 for i, g in ((a < c) & (b < d)) if i), a)
```

which return me a value of `1` and not the value of the array `a`...

The desired output array should be the one of indice `15`,`16`,`17` corresponding to the value `[3 4 4]` in array `a`.

Could someone point me to the python tools I could use in order to extract the array fulfilling my multiple conditions?

NOTE: this is a minimal example of my problem, in my "real life" I need to find arrays that meet my conditions 14 times or more consecutively!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56888201/get-groups-of-consecutive-elements-of-a-numpy-array-based-on-condition) when you looked for the elements in `array` that are less than the `threshold`, your `mask` was defined not as `mask = array < threshold` but as an inverse of it: `mask = array >= threshold`. This is because it was used later to get elements that would be *removed*.

So, in your new example, you also have to get the inverse of your mask. Instead of `mask = (a1 < c) & (a2 < d)` you need `mask = ~((a1 < c) & (a2 < d))`:

```
a1= np.append(a, -np.inf)
a2 = np.append(b, -np.inf)
mask = ~((a1 < c) & (a2 < d))
split_indices = np.where(mask)[0]
for subarray in np.split(a, split_indices + 1):
    if len(subarray) > 2:
        print(subarray[:-1])
```

gives:

```
[3 4 4]
```

which is 15-17th elements of `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the conditions, your desired output after placing the 2 conditions are: `[3,4,4]` from `a` or `[2,1,1]` from `b` right?

Try:

```
a = [1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 6, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8]
b = [2, 8, 3, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 7, 2, 1, 1, 9, 9]
c = 6
d = 3
condition_met = []
a_extract = []
b_extract = []

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    if a[i] < c and b[i] < d:
        condition_met.append(True)
    else:
        condition_met.append(False)
```

printing `condition_met` list gives `[True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, False, False]`

Using this, we now check for your conditions:

```
for i in range(0, len(condition_met)):
    if i == 0 and condition_met[i] == True and condition_met[i+1] == True:
        a_extract.append(a[i])
        b_extract.append(b[i])
    elif condition_met[i] == True and condition_met[i+1] == True and i != len(condition_met) - 1 and i > 0 or condition_met[i] == True and condition_met[i-1] == True and i != len(condition_met) - 1 and i > 0:
        a_extract.append(a[i])
        b_extract.append(b[i])
    elif condition_met[i] == True and condition_met[i-1] == True and i == len(condition_met) - 1:
        a_extract.append(a[i])
        b_extract.append(b[i])
```

You'll get `[3,4,4]` for your `a_extract` list and `[2,1,1]` for your `b_extract` list.

Is this what you need?

Comment: The `a_extract` list is the one you are looking for, I just added the `b_extract` to show versatility :)). Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: It actually works! thank you. But could you please explain me where and how the `2 times or more consecutively` condition meet, is applied in this code? Cause this is a minimal example of the task I need to do , and in my real life problem the condition need to be meet 14 times or more consecutively... :)

Comment: I see, well I did use your condition (`a < c and b < d`) to populate the `codition_met` list with boolean values (`True or False`). Now the determination of which list element to get is that positioning of those `True` or `False` value right? Basically, two straight `True`'s will meet your condition, this straight `True` is either to the left or to the right if your `i` in the second for loop is greater than 0 or less that `len(condition_met) - 1`.  if `i` equals 0 check the `0`th position in the list and the `i+1`th position. And check the `i-1`th position if `i` equals `len - 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mask using SciKit image like

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

N = 2
mask = ((a < c) & (b < d))
mask2 = np.zeros_like(mask)

tmp = skimage.util.view_as_windows(mask, N).all(axis=1)
mask2[N - 1:-N + 1] = skimage.util.view_as_windows(tmp, N).any(axis=1)
mask2
# array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
#        False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
#        False, False])
```

and get the indices and values using

```
np.where(mask2)[0]  # array([15, 16, 17])
a[mask2]  # array([3, 4, 4])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't really understand where is the "2 times or more consecutively" implemented in this code. I need for my problem to make this code work for 14 times or more consecutively.

Comment: `view_as_windows()` creates an overlapping view on the array, in this case 2 consecutive values per row. Do an `.all()` on that axis and you will know whether the condition was true for 2 consecutive values.

Comment: Thanks! But then I cannot adapt this code for 14 times or more consecutively?

Comment: Yes, just change the 2 to 14?

Comment: It does not work when I changed the 2 by any other values. Let say that I modified my arrays `a` and `b` as: `a = np.array([1, 4, 2, 6, 4, 4, 6, 2, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 8])`
`b = np.array([2, 8, 3, 9, 9, 9, 7, 5, 4, 8, 6, 5, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 9, 9])`
And that I am now searching when my conditions are meet 4 times or more consecutively, by changing the 2 by a 4. It always return me `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (14) into shape (18)`

Comment: I have updated the code so it works with `N`. Note that for `N > len(a)`, it stops working